# TypeScript allows incorrect object values to be passed if the key type is disjoint

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects, nominal-typing

I'm using [Type Flavoring](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/15/typescript-flexible-nominal-typing/) to keep different types of keys separate in my typescript app. However, I noticed that this has the strange side effect of allowing objects of the form

```
{[key: SomeFlavoredString]: ObjectA}
```

to be passed to functions that takes arguments of the form

```
{[key: SomeOtherFlavoredString]: ObjectB}
```

without complaining, which can lead to some surprising bugs. [Here's a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKClAZggLigDsBXAWwCMIAnAbiwF8tRIoAhAQxuTSx0rciZKrQaZmmFuGjw4AaQgheACgDOwGgEtiAcygAyNKwgB+IgCJ8cC4wCU4kx26LlKdZp36jqE+agWgjS2DlhYAMZwxBp4CGpEqADaANZKRHKuALrpCIy8qJwJ1kQAzIyM4pHRwFBB8Wgpac40WURcNHkoBQlBpeXiEVEx1moATAmFsLn5k6jFUGUVg9W13GMTbdydaLO9C-1hmFUxpGoQAMpw5BByaqrAABZe9UmpIDkKStlTcPbCFNQeEgAHxQADylAAVhBwsAAHQAN04ABtSBA1CpHs87IkAAyZOHWAaYU4XK43OIqOqhElnS7XW4qEajGmk+kUuAYuosuhAA)

I think what's going on is that it assumes that since the key types are disjoint, the extra keys are irrelevant and so it doesn't matter that the values at those incompatible keys are incompatible values, so it's equivalent to passing an empty object from the typescript compiler's perspective.

Is there some way to disable this or insist that my arguments can't have any incompatible values at any key? This doesn't seem like desirable behavior

Comment: I am sorry, I suppose I don't really understand your question; it seems to me that the behavior you describe is exactly what "flavoring" was designed to do (as opposed to "branding") - it accepts implicit conversion, but not explicit assignment; so it will result in an error in `const fooKey: FooKey = "x"; const barKey: BarKey = fooKey;`

Comment: @kikon An implicit conversion between `Record<SomeFlavoredString, ObjectA>` and `Record<string, ObjectA>` is fine. But an implicit conversion to `Record<string, ObjectB>` is not.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, now I see - that's quite strange indeed!

Comment: It's the same even with completely incompatible types `Foo` and `Bar`, like `type Bar = string[]`, it seems to completely forego type checking on the values side of objects.

Comment: You might be able to get somewhere by making `useSomeFoos` generic in the key type and check it with a conditional type like this https://tsplay.dev/WoAGPN. Not sure how robust this is though.

Comment: @ghybs You may have seen my comment just before I updated it to use `Record<F, V>`. The updated version does reject those cases: https://tsplay.dev/mbQ0oN

Comment: That's not too bad although using it would mean updating the types everywhere in my codebase, at which point I might as well just flavor the containers themselves